# Extract unique characters from different files in UTF-8

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to **extract unique characters** from files (**UTF-8**, contains asian characters)

I almost reach my goal but I still miss some points.

**Step 1**: Put everything in one file.

```
find ./ -name "*.ext" -exec cat {} > out.txt \;
```

**Step 2**: Delete line breaks:

```
cat out.txt |tr "\n" " ">i.txt
```

**Step 3**: ?

*I think I should sort it by unique characters, but the sort function is only for lines and not characters.*

Any help? Thanks

It could be great if I could write this command in one line!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple 1-liner in `awk`

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(!a[$i]++)print $i}' ORS= FS= *.ext
```

***Note***: Remove the `ORS=` part if you want each character on its own line

Comment: awesome. I'm new to awk and I love reading awk solutions so I can try and improve my awk-fu! :P

Comment: It won't work for Unicode characters that consist of several code points. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8906775/4279).

Answer (score 3):

If "characters" means [Grapheme Clusters](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries) aka "user-perceived characters" then the command is:

```
perl -C -ne'print grep {!$a{$_}++} /\X/g' *.ext
```

Or

```
find -name \*.ext -exec perl -C -ne'print grep {!$a{$_}++} /\X/g' {} + >uniq.out
```

To include subdirectories and redirect output to `uniq.out` file.

It reads utf-8 text from `*.ext` files and prints all unique user-perceived characters.

Note: it is different from `perl -C -ne'print grep {!$a{$_}++} split //'` that works with individual Unicode code points (similar to `awk` solution).

#### Example

```
echo é é á á é é á á |perl -C -ne'print grep {!$a{$_}++} /\X/g'
# -> é éáá

echo é é á á é é á á |perl -C -ne'print grep {!$a{$_}++} split //'
# -> é éaá

echo é é á á é é á á |awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(!a[$i]++)print $i}' ORS='' FS=''
# -> é éaá
```

Note: both 'é' and 'á' are single characters (they might be shown incorrectly: `é` and `á`).

To see the difference here's code points with their names.

#### Input

```
'e\u0301' LATIN SMALL LETTER E
          COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
' '       SPACE
'é'       LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE
' '       SPACE
'a\u0301' LATIN SMALL LETTER A
          COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
' '       SPACE
'á'       LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE
' '       SPACE
'e\u0301' LATIN SMALL LETTER E
          COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
' '       SPACE
'é'       LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE
' '       SPACE
'a\u0301' LATIN SMALL LETTER A
          COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
' '       SPACE
'á'       LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE
```

#### `/\X/g`-based Output

```
'e\u0301' LATIN SMALL LETTER E
          COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
' '       SPACE
'é'       LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE
'a\u0301' LATIN SMALL LETTER A
          COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
'á'       LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE
```

#### awk and `split //`-based Output

```
'e\u0301' LATIN SMALL LETTER E
          COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
' '       SPACE
'é'       LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE
'a'       LATIN SMALL LETTER A
'á'       LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE
```

The second output misses the last `COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT` that is part of `'á '` character. it prints just `'a'` (`LATIN SMALL LETTER A`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't stated `perl` as a tag please disregard this answer if you don't find it appropriate. I could not test it much since you haven't posted sample data but you can give it a try -

```
perl -e 'while(<>){chomp;$uniqchar{$_}++ for split(//, $_)}print keys %uniqchar,"\n";' *.ext
```

Comment: It is simpler: `perl -ne'print grep {!$a{$_}++} split //' *.ext` It should work without `-C` option.

Comment: Thanks @J.F.Sebastian for the feedback. I am still learning `perl` so you may find my one-liner to be abnormally long.

Comment: You can replace the `while (<>)` with `-n` (though then you'll need to put the final `print` in an `END` block) and the `chomp` (and `print "\n"`) with `-l`. You might need to add `-CSD` in order for it to work correctly with Unicode.